# Date formats union in XSD

Tags: xml, date, xsd, xsd-validation

I have defined the following simple type in a XSD:

```
<xs:simpleType name="myDateFormat">
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:dateTime xs:date xs:gYearMonth xs:gYear"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I would like to allow YYYY, YYYY-MM, YYYY-MM-DD and full datetime formats. But after doing some testing I have realised that I don't get an error with the following values:

- 2006999
- 20061302
- 2006999999

How can I create a type that allows only YYYY, YYYY-MM, YYYY-MM-DD and full datetime?

EDIT1: Is this a possible solution?

```
<xs:simpleType name="myDateFormat">
    <xs:union>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:gYear">
                <xs:pattern value="\d{4}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:gYearMonth">
                <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-\d{2}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
                <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>    
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
                <xs:pattern value="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>        
    </xs:union>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend against allowing a free-form field. An elegant data structure will require an exact syntax, to avoid the risk of ambiguity, and to allow client code to know what to expect from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `xs:gYear` that's allowing the unwanted values.  (It's allowing them as years with more than 4 digits.)

You can define your own year that's limited to 4 digits:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="gYear4">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:nonNegativeInteger">
      <xs:totalDigits value="4"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

And use that instead in your `xs:union`:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="myDateFormat">
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:dateTime xs:date xs:gYearMonth gYear4"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

And then the values you want will be allowed, and the `YYYY[YYYYYY]` values that you do not will be prohibited, as requested.

Comment: Thanks kjhughes! I think I have the same problem with gYearMonth, it allows 20000-12. I think I have come up with a solution.

Comment: Great. Very usefull!!